# How can I execute a command anywhere if certain required files are different directories?

Tags: linux, path, command, working-directory

Let say the command be `my_command`

And this command has to be prepared specific files (file1, file2, and file3) in the current working directory.

Because I often use `my_command` in many different directories, I'd like to keep the certain files in a certain directory and execute `my_command` without those three files in the working directory.
I mean I don't want to copy those three files to every working directory.

For example:

Directory containing the three files `/home/chest`

Working directory: `/home/wd`

If I execute command `my_command`, it automatically recognizes the three files in `/home/chest/`

I've thought the way is similar to add $PATH and not the executable files but just files.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem is in this case? Why can you not just create a directory under let's say your home folder and add all needed files in to it and then simply use an absolute path to the files from your script? I think you'll need to explain a little more about what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Yes, command what I'm using now requires certain files in the working directory whenever I execute it. And as you mentioned, how can I make it retrieve or use those specific files in the absolute path? And I couldn't fix the command inside. That's the problem.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add an example from your command where you try to use the actual files. I think this should in fact be very easy to solve.

Comment: Here is the command. `mpirun -np 4 vasp_std`. And the vasp_std required some files over 10. I couldn't fix that vasp_std because it is provided from outside which is not my script.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the entire content of your script?

Comment: In that case you’ll need to show how the vasp_std script is using the files.

Comment: One other question should the requied files used by the `vasp_std` command be keept in a separate folder in the current directory?

Comment: Why would a command "recognize" files? It really depends what that command is doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the files needs to be in the current working directory for the `vasp_std` command to work as expected, I am thinking that you could simply add all files in a include folder in you home directory and then create a symbolic link to this folder from your script. In the end of your script the symbolic link will then be deleted:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create a symbolic link to our resource folder
ln -s ~/include src

# execute other commands here

# finally remove the symbolic link from the current directory
unlink src
```

If the `vasp_std` command require that the files are placed directly under the current working directory you could instead create a symbolic link for each file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create link for to all resource files
for file in ~/include/*
do
  ln -s $file `basename $file`
done

# execute other commands here

# remove any previously created links
for file in ~/include/*
do
  unlink `basename $file`
done
```

Comment: I've thought using link is the final hope. But because of you, I've just learned the `unlink` command. I think it is very easy to handle for existing symbolic links. Thanks! And the latter is suitable for me.

Comment: @NokiLee - Or did you solve it? Did it actually work in your specific case using symbolic links?

Comment: @NokiLee - Notice that there is no need to use an abolute path since the tilde will be expanded to your `HOME` directory.